# Why isn't GTAG/GA4 tracking anything inside an iFrame?

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I need to track analytics of my web-widgets, used by my clients with an iFrame.
I import GTAG inside my page (referred to the iframe) but it doesn't track anything.

For instance, a customer of mine wants to put my button "Button1" inside his page. So he will have

```html
<!-- customer hosting "parent" website -->
<body>
...
  <iframe src="https://danieles_webwidget.com/button1.html">
...
</body>
```

The referred page of the iframe, hosted by my domain (danieles_webwidget.com) has the html to render a button, and the GTAG script import

```html
<!-- "child" Button1 widget page at https://danieles_webwidget.com/button1.html-->

<head>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
   <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->     
</head>

<body>
   <!-- render the button -->
   <button class="btn">
      Click me!
   </button>

    
   <!-- track analytics with custom events -->
    <script>
      jQuery('.btn').on("click", function()
        {
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            var body = {'event'            : "button_clicked", 
                        'custom_event'     : "true", 
                        'custom_label'     : "bla bla bla"
                        };
            window.dataLayer.push(body);
            console.log("Done!"); // debug purpose
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

So,the code works, the button is showed on my customer website, and if I click on the button, I can see on the console the debug message "Done!". Anyway I don't see any stats on google Analytics.
Why?
If I directly open the page button1.html, events are correctly tracked.

This is my configuration in GTAG:

**TAG**

```
configuration tag: GA4
event name: "button_clicked"
event params: "Custom Label" : {{custom_label}}
```

**TRIGGERS**

```
type: custom event
event name: "button_clicked"
on: all events
```

I know that in this way, I can loose the source, i.e. the hosting URL using the iframe, but it's a secondary problem. For now, I just need to track clicks. I know I could use `parent.postMessage()`, but unfortunately I haven't control of parent websites, and also I don't want them to change their privacy policy.

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately no..

Answer (score 0):

You insert a `GTM` snippet and placing `datalayer.push` which is good.

But you need to setup more to finish.

1. Check the datalayer is showing on your GTM preview.
2. Setup the trigger according with your event name in datalayer.
3. Setup the tag using GA4 event to track what you want.

The method you use is not a `gtag` function only. So GA4 is not receiving data if you don't setup the setting above.

---

There is another way call `parent.postMessage` which is sending information from iframe to parent.

You can have a look and decide which way is closer to your analytics requirement.

---

Here is how I test for the iframe :

Right click on the element from the iframe inside

->
Choose inspect to open the devtool

->
Choose `console` tab, to check if the window is on iframe domain

If yes, then you can console the datalayer to check if it is as expected.

[image]

On the `network` tab. I can see my GTM is loaded in request.

Comment: I’m going to update my question with more details. Actually I already created custom events and trigger in GTAG. If I visit my page directly, without the iframe, events are correctly tracked

Comment: just edited, adding tag and trigger

Comment: Thanks for the update. So I guess in the preview, there is no datalayer showing up in the debug mode right?

Comment: right. If I directly open the "child page", yes. But if I open the parent page hosting the iframe, the debug shows `Google Tag: GTM-XXXXX not found`

Comment: I add a comment. If I analyze the DOM of the parent page with inspector, actually I see inside the iframe the <script> containing the GTM-XXXXX import

Comment: in the browser network console, from the parent page, I don't see any entry `collect` to googletagmanager.com

Comment: I have a case using the same method. But it is working as expected. So the problem  might be the 3rd party cookie issue or the parent is blocking your GTM.

Comment: just made a `console.log(window.dataLayer)`, and all the events are tracked also from the parent. They are just not sent. I really don't understand why. I'm testing on a parent page of my property, which test and check could I do? thank you

Comment: Add some information about how I test my iframe case.

Comment: done. I can see the correct GTM.js loaded from the parent website. making a `console.log(windows.dataLayer)` shows all the events correctly tracked. From the network debug, just the `dataLayer.push`
 are missing

Comment: But in my case the GTM preview is working fine. Maybe that is the first issue need to resolved.

Comment: tried using other parent domains, to exclude some restriction filter on domains, ip etc..  always same result. GTM preview doesn't see the gtag, even if its present in the network console. Is there any settings I should enable to let it work in iframe? I really don't know what to check