# Why is GTAG not being found in an iFrame by GTAG Debug Preview?

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

trying to solve this other question [Why isn't GTAG/GA4 tracking anything inside an iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76363929/why-isnt-gtag-ga4-tracking-anything-inside-an-iframe/76369571?noredirect=1#comment134671847_76369571) trying to change view of the problem.

I have pageA that has an iframe pointing to pageB (different domains). PageB renders just a button.
Into pageB is installed a GTAG linked to GA4, to track clicks on the button.

- If I directly visit pageB, links are tracked and GTAG works fine.
- If I visit pageA, no data from pageB are sent.

Trying to debug with console and inspector, I see that:

- from pageA, network console shows that gtag.js is correctly loaded;
- however, GTAG debug says "gtag not found" on pageA;
- if in pageB I use `console.log(window.dataLayer)`, from pageA I see that dataLayer  has all the events correctly tracked;
- from pageA, on the network console no traffic is reported when `dataLayer.push()` is triggered;
- console.log() on pageA shows that `dataLayer.push()` is executed.
- everything accessing directly to pageB works

I really don't know what else to find and check. What could be the problem?

**PageA**

```html
<body>
...
  <iframe src="https://danieles_webwidget.com/button1.html">
...
</body>
```

**PageB**

```html
<head>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
   <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->     
</head>

<body>
   <!-- render the button -->
   <button class="btn">
      Click me!
   </button>

    
   <!-- track analytics with custom events -->
    <script>
      jQuery('.btn').on("click", function()
        {
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            var body = {'event'            : "button_clicked", 
                        'custom_event'     : "true", 
                        'custom_label'     : "bla bla bla"
                        };
            window.dataLayer.push(body);
            console.log("Done!"); // debug purpose
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
```